# Unable to run Dev Container in VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-11

I am trying to use a Dev Container in Visual Studio Code and getting the below error when trying with the sample container

```
[2024-01-26T17:04:29.564Z] Command failed: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.327.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-27da0101-0dec-406c-a14b-b67b2cea9b291706288651690 --workspace-folder /workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=vscode-remote-try-python-57162747f0204512b2a2119607d864e61e3cfb714da0e7ce0cf5751654850e99 --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=vscode-remote-try-python --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/vscode-remote-try-python/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --override-config /tmp/devcontainer-8fe087f6-0e05-4637-97b8-aaffdc81588e.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode-remote-try-python-57162747f0204512b2a2119607d864e61e3cfb714da0e7ce0cf5751654850e99,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root
```

##### Additional Info:

Docker Desktop - 4.20.1 (110738)